# Energy required to demagnetize a soft iron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields

How much energy is required to demagnetize a soft iron ferromagnetic material, that has a very low coercive force And a small hysteresis area?

Also, would it be possible to demagnetize that same soft iron while it's aligned with an exterior magnetic field via vibrations from hammering/dropping?
**The hammering is constant so the vibrations should be constant as well.** 
That's why I assume it can be demagnetized.

Comment: The amount of energy would be dependent on the amount of material.  Perhaps you're thinking temperature instead?  Then the amount of energy needed would be calculated from the temperature delta, the material, and the amount of the material.

Comment: Well, what I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to demagnetize a soft iron ferromagnetic material with the presence of an exterior magnetic field by hammering it constantly, and introducing some vibrations to it as well. I'm wondering if it is easy to demagnetize them? Since they have very low coercive forces.